# Calculating Time duration in seconds pyspark

Tags: datetime, pyspark

I am trying to calculate time difference in seconds below is my try,

```
from datetime import datetime
aa = sc.parallelize[('10:40:31', '10:39:31')]
FMT = "%H:%M:%S"
duration = aa.map(lambda p: (datetime.strptime(p[0], FMT) - datetime.strptime(p[1], FMT) ))
```

**gives me [datetime.timedelta(0, 60)]**  but i want difference in seconds only like 60 only.

How could i do that i tried with .total_seconds() but it is not working

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue,

I need to add one more map with .seconds

```
 duration = aa.map(lambda p: (datetime.strptime(p[0], FMT) - datetime.strptime(p[1], FMT) )).map(lambda l: l.seconds)
```

will give,

```
  [60]
```